# Как решить проблему? telegrambot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

У меня есть код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ла-ла-ла-ла')
    return(chat_id)






def help():
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Памагити!!!")
```

после выдаёт ошибку:

```
#Ошибка в help()
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждую функцию, которая будет обрабатывать события бота, нужно обернуть в отдельный декоратор.

У вас же одна функция обёрнута в декоратор, соответствующий обоим событиям, а вторая функция осталась голой.

Нужно так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])        # Убрал help отсюда
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ла-ла-ла-ла')
    return(chat_id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])         # Добавил декоратор с help сюда
def help(message):                              # И дописал аргумент message
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Памагити!!!")
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет переменной 'message', вашим решением является - объявление этой переменной.

```
def help(message):
   chat_id = message.from_user.id
   bot.send_message(chat_id, "Памагити!!!")
```